# How to submit classic asp page on dropdown onchange event?

Tags: asp-classic

I have dropdown html control on classic asp page inside div tag. How to submit classic asp page on dropdown onchange event? I have tried . But did not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
/*Use this following coding for submiting a form by changing drop down box*/
<form method="post" name="frmsubmit" action="page.asp"> 
<select name="options" onChange="javascript: document.forms['frmsubmit'].submit()"> 
<option selected>Select</option> 
<option value="Op1">1</option> 
<option value="Op2">2</option> 
<option value="Op3">3</option> 
</select> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript, and put the function call in the onchange event of your dropdown control.

```
<script>
  void PostForm() {
    // submit all your values here
  }
</script>
<select onchange="PostForm()"></select>
```

Comment: I am getting "Object doesn't support this property or method" if i give onChange='document.all.form.Submit();'